# Preflight fails in one Angular client but not another

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've created a WebApi application using the Individual Accounts authentications template, and I've enabled CORS to allow various clients to use my services.  I configured CORS to allow all origins ("*").  I've also created an Angular front-end, which successfully retrieves a token for use when calling secure routes.  However, the client is unable to call the Logout action because of a failed pre-flight check.

While troubleshooting the issue, I created a separate solution using the instructions found in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En).  The new solution works great, so I pointed the client of the new solution to my original WebApi project and it also works great.  This has led me to believe there is something different between Angular clients, but I haven't found the significant difference.

Could someone review the code below and point out the difference between the client that works and the client that fails?

This is the Angular code within the application that works:

*App configuration*

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    // Override $http service's default transformRequest
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
    // Converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
    }];
}]);
```

*In my factory*

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: logoutUrl,
    headers: getHeaders(),
}).then(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
    accessToken = null;
    deferred.resolve({ status: 'success' });
}, function (err, status) {
    console.log(err);
    deferred.reject(status);
});
return deferred.promise;

function getHeaders() {
    if (accessToken) {
        return { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken };
    }
}
```

Here's the raw HTTP request that goes through.  The OPTIONS preflight check passes, so the POST goes through.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:56508/api/Account/Logout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56508
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:42458
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:42458/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

POST http://localhost:56508/api/Account/Logout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56508
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:42458
Authorization: Bearer fNKcX_jCNhQuIhorMw-QPyezReQJd5ehoVhqegUmSQZxdbHp-T6L4RPehSl6ihSpNbYH58uhELwNHV0bEAyRj0G7bmFv4O5GIqBDyiOIB-YBfez5zHRNHbMe_iTdtBwdgOdbLh5PNSNIOi4ffU6H-py4oko0rMkLSP_hFSl2TGcbJwuJkrmHmahmLyeyQ-OO8KI4Kc-WoTaIVw3dJ5LDxbdSFF9aWoaCVGDfbP1tcp-aTMmydqZLnkX5DAGQPDawsiuXuWuwvUDPz6f4K5F78r4D8ldl8cCSO0uniSv3mIZYbgDuzwfjIrV_lN5pFYHg38f-7RcwvE-TARr0wJ1dNcM9XnNTJRXxsJRpJP-LAG369smEnRk2Z2D7Gds0KCAK7zKcwRyJh8u7_YCLcMVJR97mhJk-n4zEfnD3yxa0VsiNHkHiAAjtXF78ASWBW2LXXYlvn0Mu0tcltZ7Qur9-TslHjUhD1BmNkQzwTkQte3kbMk7HsCDZCWaxr-j_8ApD
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:42458/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

This is the Angular code within the application that fails:

*In my factory*

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: logoutUrl,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        ,'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
    },
}).then(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
    accessToken = null;
    deferred.resolve({ status: 'success' });
}, function (err, status) {
    console.log(err);
    deferred.reject(status);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Here's the raw HTTP request that goes through.  The OPTIONS preflight check fails here, so the POST doesn't go through.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:56508/api/Account/Logout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56508
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:45743
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:45743/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: The preflight looks the same, it should work fine. Are both clients calling the same service?

Comment: Yes, both are calling the same service.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the problem was not with my $http request or with CORS.  The problem occurred because I called an asynchronous function as though it was synchronous, and the request was canceled before it had a chance to finish.

Here's an example of the code that was poorly written.  The Logout function encapsulates the $http request.

```
    authService.logout();
    $window.location.href = location.origin;
```

Here's an example of the code as it should have been written. This code works as expected.

```
    authService.logout().then(function success(data){
        $window.location.href = location.origin;
    }, function failure(data) {
        $window.location.href = location.origin;
    });
```

Without waiting for the promise to resolve causes the $http to execute the error callback, but the error object is unavailable.  Therefore, I thought the preflight failed when in fact the POST was prematurely canceled by the client.